# Suggestions for quickly creating elements

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm you can create elements quickly typing `element.class#id`. For example to create a div with a class of foo, I'd type `div.foo` and hit tab. However, it doesn't suggest CSS classes when typing this way. If I create a div manually and start typing within the class attribute, it will autocomplete. Can I enable this when using this shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, but not by default.

Abbreviation functionality you asking is provided by [Emmet plugin](http://emmet.io/) as far I know. In IntelliJ IDEA we can find [EmmetEverywhere plugin](https://dej.in.ua/emmet-everywhere/). You can download it from PyCharm by browsing `Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories` and type `Emmet` in search box.